# Sharing array inside object through classes in php

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

My problem is that I have an object shared through two classes that contains an array inside of it and along the script, someone will request some of the classes the value and a foreach loop will change such value and I want this change to affect every reference of the value.

```
class bar {

    protected $obj;

    function __construct(&$obj) {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function output() {
        print_r($this->obj->value);
    }

}

class foo {

    protected $obj;

    function __construct(&$obj) {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function val() {
        $result = array();
        foreach($this->obj->value as $it){
            $result[] = $it;
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
// Shared Object
$obj = new stdClass();
// Default value
$obj->value = array('teste', 'banana', 'maca');
// Class 1
$bar = new bar($obj);
// Class 2
$foo = new foo($obj);

// Someone requests from class 2 the values and changes it
$new = $foo->val();
$new[] = 'abc';

// Class 1 outputs the value
$bar->output(); // this will print the default value. I want this to also have 'abc' value.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem, is that you are building a new array at foo:val, you must return the original object to be modified.

I suggest use [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php), have the same behavior of array but is a object, then always is passed by reference.

```
<?php

class MyArrayObject extends ArrayObject {
    public function replace(Array $array)
    {
        foreach($this->getArrayCopy() as $key => $value) {
            $this->offsetUnset($key);
        }

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $this[$key] = $value;
        }
    }


}

class bar {

    protected $obj;

    function __construct(MyArrayObject $obj) {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function output() {
        print_r($this->obj);
    }

}

class foo {

    protected $obj;

    function __construct(MyArrayObject $obj) {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function val() {
        $result = array('foo', 'bar');
        $this->obj->replace($result);

        return $this->obj;
    }

}
// Shared Object
$obj = new MyArrayObject(array('teste', 'banana', 'maca'));
// Class 1
$bar = new bar($obj);
// Class 2
$foo = new foo($obj);

// Someone requests from class 2 the values and changes it
$new = $foo->val();
$new[] = 'abc';

// Class 1 outputs the value
$bar->output(); // this will print the default value. I want this to also 

var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: My problem is that I actually filter the array before returning it, that's why I'm "building a new array". I'd like this new array to point to the original values.

Comment: the arrayobject is your choose you can empty it and fill it again.

Comment: I may have not been fair on the question since my values were being filtered and they weren't primitive, it was actually objects. Building a new function inside the class of objects that changes itself did the trick. But thanks, you showed me that the problem was the creation of new arrays.