# Sharing an array of objects across classes in php

Tags: php, multithreading, design-patterns, pass-by-reference, ratchet

I have a scenario where an array of objects (Players) must be read and modified by objects of other classes. Those objects will work on the same array, that is, **any change to the array is seen by all objects.** Anything is likely to modify the array including threads and IO event functions.

Here are the specifics:

```
class Player {
    public $connection;
    public $x,$y,$velocity;

    public function __construct(ConnectionInterface $conn, $initx, $inity) 
    { /* ... */ }

    public function updateVelocity($newVelocity) { /* ... */ }
}

$players_arr = array();

class ConnectionClass extends Thread implements MessageComponentInterface {
    private $players;

    // A new player connected
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) { 
    // ...
        array_push($this->players, new Player($conn, x, y);
    }

    public function run() {
        while(true) {
            // ...
            foreach ($this->players as $player) 
                $player->connection->send(data);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }

}

class World extends Thread {
    private $players;

    public function run() {
        while(true) {
            // ...
            foreach ($this->players as $player) 
                $player->updateVelocity($vel);
            usleep(30000);
        }
    }

}
```

$players in `World` and in `ConnectionClass` should always be identical!!

The `ConnectionInterface` and `MessageComponentInterface` are part of "Ratchet" a Web-Socket library I'm using. Also, if it makes any difference, each class is in its own .php file.

**How should I structure the code?**

Should I make the shared array static in `Player` class itself? if so, how to access it from other classes?

Things I've tried:

- passing a reference of `$players_arr` to the classes' constructors and assigning it to `$players`: got `cannot assign by reference to overloaded object` error.
  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082788
- using `ArrayObject`: adding a `new Player()` to it in `onOpen()` is not yielding no effects. (Could have done wrong?)
  [Sharing array inside object through classes in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224376/sharing-array-inside-object-through-classes-in-php)

Note: I'm aware that multi-threaded access to the array requires special measures and synchronization (**Please elaborate**), but the main issue is how to share the array across classes (not necessarily threads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the purpose that the `World` and `ConnectionClass` are extending the `Thread` class is to share same $players this won't work.

As far as I can get your problem a new instance of `ArrayObject` should do the job, you just have pass it's instance to the `World`'s and `ConnectionClass`'s instances:

```
$players = new ArrayObject();
$connection = new ConnectionClass($players); //add it to the other arguments if any
$world = new World($players); //add it to the other arguments if any

//or you can with setter

$players = new ArrayObject();
$connection = new ConnectionClass();
$connection->setPlayers($players);
$world = new World($players);
$world-> setPlayers($players);
```

You should change the controllers of your `World` and `ConnectionClass` to initiate the `private $players` property with the new argument, or implement a setter.

```
public function __construct($players)
{
     $this->players = $players;
}

//or

public function setPlayers($players)
{
     $this->players = $players;
}
```

You should also change `onOpen`'s implemention:

```
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) { 
// ...
    $this->players->append(new Player($conn, x, y));
}
```

Comment: Upon appending in onOpen(), the count is still zero
(Already mentioned in question)

Comment: Are you passing the same ArrayObject instance? Can you paste here the code eith the ArrayObject implementation?

Comment: when `extends Thread` is removed, appending suddenly does work.

Comment: "when extends Thread is removed, appending suddenly does work" this means you have to search for the problem there

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the help, this should get me going. Need to read "pthread" documentation and see how extending a Thread  affects the class.